# Getting Session Value from ScalatraTest-ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalatra

I am currently writing a number of Scalatra tests using the ScalaTest framework and the ScalatraSuite class.

```
  test("when i try to go to the base url it shold redirect me "){
    get("/") {
      status should be(302) 
    }
  }
```

The next step requires me to check the existance of some session values but it is unclear how to do this?  Can anyone advise?  I am creating a SessionAccess trait that, for the purposes of the test, overriding witha  simple trait the stores session in an accessible HashMap but I am certain there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the code of ScalatraSuite and it looks like there is no way to retrieve the session object itself. You can however execute multiple calls inside of a session to check for the expected behaviour.

If you had these calls:

```
post("/start") {
  session("foo") = params("foo")
  // ...
}

get("/do_something") {
  session.get("foo")
}
```

you could test it like this:

```
test("Whatever inside of a session") {
  session {
    post("/start", "foo" -> "bar") {
      // assert...
    }
    get("/do_something") {
      body should equal ("bar")
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thats what I thought.  Thanks for confirming.